# .gitignore file is not stopping the directory from getting committed

Tags: git, push, gitignore

I'm trying to gitignore all files in the data directory so in my gitignore file I am writing

```
#ignore data files
data/*
```

This doesn't seem to be ignoring the files because when I go to push a commit I am having the issue that files from that directory are too large so the push is failing.

Comment: When you're pushing your commits - it's *already too late* to ignore anything since it has already been committed.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
#ignore data files
data/
```

Anyways I  would suggest you do a

```
git rm data/
```

and then check whether it is getting added again. Hope this helps.

Comment: this isn't working for me.  These files are some pre-allocated stuff from adding mongodb to the directory.  I think I'm gonna need to remove that and then I'll be fine.  Also git supports the * now.  I think the sans * style is older school git.  Thanks for your help though, you'd be right if this wasn't some weird mongo thing... For some reason the files don't even show up until I try to push it, even though the directory structure is there.  I guess because it's pre-allocated.